# Can Elastic Search be used as a NoSQL database

Tags: elasticsearch

In my case, I need to store user specific event metadata and show it in the user inbox sorted by created date in paginated form. This has to be shown when the user logs into the system, there will be an inbox icon. Once the user clicks on the icon, user specific events will be shown in batches of 20. Can I use elasticsearch as a data store.

Comment: Yes. Elasticsearch is quite good. I am not sure about your usage or storage needs. If you are looking for a easier and cost-effective solution, then I would recommend Amazon DynamoDB (check out AWS free-tier) since you seem to have limited requirements.

Comment: I am looking at whether Elastic Search can be used as a NoSQL primary database which can run range queries. My system will have many users, and there will be many requests, so it should be scalable. DynamoDb can be used, but I am specifically looking for pros and cons in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to use Elasticsearch as a primary storage, but there are some limitation in it. Kindly refer this link for the limitations [enter link description here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-elasticsearch-as-nosql)

Comment: That's an old article, a lot has changed since.

Comment: Yes Nikhil. It's old but this has a very basic things which is absolutely necessary. I hope to getting started it's will help.

Comment: I am specifically looking for pros and cons in using elasticsearch as NoSQL database. Scalability is one aspect I am looking at. I could not find any literature on the internet wherein anyone has used Elasticsearch as a NoSQL database.